# How to wrap synchronous method that returns `void` into Mono<Void>?

Tags: java, spring-boot, project-reactor, reactor, spring-reactor

I'm trying to adapt the postgresql repository `deleteById` method which return `void` to return `Mono<Void>`

the repository is a service that I autowired, I use it like this

`repository.deleteById(id)` with String id as the argument

Comment: How do you call the repository?

Comment: the repository is a service that I autowired, I use it like this

`repository.deleteById(id)` with String id as the argument

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use reactive stack, then you should use [spring-data-r2dbc](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc), which provides `ReactiveCrudRepository` and method `Mono<Void> deleteById(ID id)`.

If for some reason you need to use a synchronous method, then you could wrap `deleteById` call using [Mono.fromRunnable](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#fromRunnable-java.lang.Runnable-)

```
Mono.fromRunnable(() -> repository.deleteById(someId))
```

However, this should be avoided, because then you get no benefits of using reactive stack.

Comment: Depending on what OP needs R2DBC might suffice as it provides a decent reactive repository implementation, but is still very lacking in terms of features (it does not support entity relationships, embedding, etc.)

Comment: The question was whether or not using a reacitve stack with sql database is a good idea. As far as I know currently spring-r2dbc is the best option for this case and it gets better. It still lacks many features from synchronous world, but embeeded database is already supported

Comment: Thank you, I might upgrade spring-data-r2dbc later, but right now I want to try to wrap the synchronous repository (using JPA) to "reactive". By the way what is the different of `Mono.fromRunnable(() -> repository.deleteById(someId))` and using `Mono.create(sink -> failedKafkaRepository.deleteById(id))`? I found this yesterday and not quite sure if it achieve the same thing as `Mono.fromRunnable`

Comment: In reactive programming, you need to send a signal/event to next processor in order to pass to it some data, error or just inform that no value will be passed, so it can stop listening. If you use `Mono.create`, then your Callable function gets a `sink`, which can be used to manually send an event. More information can be found in the documentation https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#create-java.util.function.Consumer- ;)

Comment: switching your repository-abstraction is a huge deal, since you can't use reactive and non-reactive repositories on the same table in the same application and you probably have many things depending on your repository. This is like answering "how to replace a broken car window" with "buy a new car" or "take the train".